# Set up License Programmatically

Tags: registry, enterprise-architect, license-key

I would like to set `Enterprise Architect` shared key license programmatically for each user.

What are the registry keys to be updated? Is there another `appdata` file or table to modify?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [deployment whitepaper published by Sparx](http://www.sparxsystems.com/downloads/whitepapers/EA_Deployment.pdf)

Appendix 9 on page 22 says:

> 1. Example registry settings for the file based keystore:  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\EA400\EA\OPTIONS] 
>      "SKT"=hex:00 "SharedKeyFolder"=" Y:\Dev\Licenses"
>      "AutoCheckoutEx"=hex:1a,00,00,00
> 2. Example registry settings for the service based keystore:  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\EA400\EA\OPTIONS] 
>      "SKT"=hex:01 "SSKSAddress"="ssks://pathToKeystoreService"
>      "SSKSPassword"="service password (encrypted)"
>      "AutoCheckoutEx"=hex:1a,00,00,00

I hope the document is still up to date.

Comment: I hope too.. I've found these mentioned registry keys. After I release the existing license key, they still have the same content. Thoughts?

Comment: @user3165438 Seems logical that these values don't change. All they do is point to the location of the shared license (server).

Comment: Then, How EA knows that he has no license key, if the registry points to the right shared license server? What else is modified? Thanks.

Comment: @user3165438 who has checked-out a license is managed by the license server, not on the EA client.